# Strange $ character in json output

Tags: php, json

I'm reading the json output from this file and have the decoded json stored in a var called $json.

> http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoogleDevelopers/uploads?v=2&alt=json

What I then want to do is read the value of `openSearch$totalResults":` but it has a strange `$` character. How should I read this value which is 999 in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell PHP to use the string as the attribute.

```
...->{'openSearch$totalResults'}->...
```

Answer (score 0):

$ is a perfectly legal character in a variable name in javascript.  You just read the value as you would any other, using json_decode.  You'll have to escape the $ when you access the variable though.

```
<? print_r(json_decode('{"this$name" : "value"}') ); ?>
result: stdClass Object ( [this$name] => value )
```

Comment: I believe he wants to know how to do it in PHP.